# c# WebClient downloading file from url to desired directory doesnt (really) work

Tags: c#, winforms, webclient

i am new to c# and visual studio windows forms. i tried to make a installer just to see how c# works but i have a little problem.
with my "program" you first select where you want to download the file and and then you click on the download button to download.
so i select where i want the file to be but it does something weird.
so you select the folder and download the file but it downloads the file (which is called test.txt)
with the text CHROMEtest.txt (i selected chrome as my installation directory)
My chrome folder is in my desktop folder, so i select chrome as my download folder but then it installs as CHROMEtest.txt on my desktop.
its probably because i use  textBox1.Text as directory.
i am going to post the code here for understanding.

Strings:

````
        string url1 = "https://www.dropbox.com/s/f8f3x5qgmkeqis6/test.txt?dl=1";
        string fileName1 = "text.txt";```

code:
````

olderBrowserDialog fbd = new FolderBrowserDialog();

```
    private void folderbrowser_Click_1(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {


        if (fbd.ShowDialog() == DialogResult.OK)
        {
            textBox1.Text = fbd.SelectedPath;
        }
    }
    private void Install_Button_Click_1(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {


        if (textBox1.Text.Length > 0)
        {
            //Downloading file form Http Url
            WebClient myWebClient = new WebClient();
            myWebClient.DownloadFile(url1, textBox1.Text + fileName1);
            //CompleteDownloading file form Http Url
        }
        else
        {
            MessageBox.Show("File path not found!", "Error", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Exclamation);

        }


    }
```

```
i hope you guys can help me :D
```

Comment: Use `Path.Combine(textBox1.Text, fileName1)`. Because when the folder specified does not have the trailing backslash, the path will be <dir>\CHROME<fileName1>. Path.Combine covers these cases

Comment: `fbd.SelectedPath` is a full path, so you don't have just `CHROMEtest.txt`. You just need `Path.Combine()`, as already suggested. This methods build a path for you. You also need to create a new instance of the WebClient object with a `using` statement: `using var myWebClient = new WebClient() { myWebClient.DownloadFile(...); ... }`. So the WebClient object is disposed after its task is completed.

Comment: I dont really understand how to use path.combine in my code. sorry im new and my english isnt that great.